# Need a regexr to fetch the multiple data

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need a regrex to get the value in the below format

Code=ABC&cellNo=314&payType=0&transmission=MANUAL&vendorId=ET&toggleSelctd=0&uniqueId=39

This is a sample code is attached in the below screenshot

but however the regrex which i have created fetches data for one value but i need the same in the above format, for example below are the regrex.

1. name="cellNo" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" value="(.+?)
2. name="transmission" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"

Thanks
[image: 1]

Comment: what have you tried and what exactly you want to get?

Comment: @user7294900 : i have tried to fetch the data using each one regexr which is working fine but incase of such  getting data in this combination i am not able to fetch it

Comment: @user7294900 : Like this one :name="cellNo" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" value="(.+?) and name="payType" type="hidden" value="()" and name="transmission" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" but unable to get in the above set of combination

Comment: in case of value="" what you want it to return?

Comment: @user7294900 : the value which is mention for ex name="transmission" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" .. this value contains "MANUAL" like that

Comment: guys please dont downvote this question i m really new into this and in need of this solution.. i am updating this question in much more simpler way.. for you guys to look for hence added directly the screenshot

Comment: Maybe you should remove those duplicate attributes first. 
i.e. regex replace `((\w+)="[^"]+"\s+)\2="[^"]*"\s*` by `$1`.  Then use an xml parser to get the name and value attributes.

Comment: @LukStorms : ohk.. and what if want this in regex is then like .. the one above i mention.

Comment: Anyway, using `value="(.+?)" value="(.+?)"` on a string that has `"value="ET" value=""` won't work because it expect at least one character between the quotes in the second value.

Comment: @LukStorms : ohk....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748). JMeter offers [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) for fetching data from the HTML pages so you should be able to extract the required values using the following configurations:

1. For `MANUAL`:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `transmission`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[id=transmission]`
   - Attribute: `value`
2. For `314`

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `CellNo`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[id=CellNo]`
   - Attribute: `value`

See [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) article for more information.

---

I think response markup is a little bit flaky as [HTML input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) cannot have 2 name and 2 value tags, I would recommend using JMeter's [HTML Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Assertion) or online [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to check response data and raise issues on validation errors.